# Elegant way to parse a 1-many column into a new data.frame in R

Tags: r, reshape

I have some data read in from an excel spreadsheet where the curators are not aware of relational databases and handling 1-many relationships, so have put multiple variables in one column:

```
>df <- data.frame(id=c("X1", "X23", "X5"), vars=c("foo, bar, hello", "world", NA), var2=c(1,2,3))
>df
   id            vars var2
1  X1 foo, bar, hello    1
2 X23           world    2
3  X5            <NA>    3
```

I want to transform the `vars` column to a new data frame so I can have a 1-many relation:

```
>df
     id var2
X1   X1    1
X23 X23    2
X5   X5    3

>df2
   id   var
1  X1   foo
2  X1   bar
3  X1 hello
4 X23 world
```

I am able to parse the `vars` column into a list where each entry is a vector of variables:

```
>library(stringr)
>halfway <- str_split(df$vars, pattern=", ")
>halfway
[[1]]
[1] "foo"   "bar"   "hello"

[[2]]
[1] "world"

[[3]]
[1] NA
```

but I'm unsure how to take this list and transform it to a long `data.frame`.

I've had a play around, but I can't get it into the long format without losing information about the IDs each of the variables belongs to (using `unlist`). 
I've also looked at `reshape` but it doesn't seem to do what I want.

I could use a for loop to iteratively build up the new table, but that's horribly inefficient. Is there an elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done in a very straightforward way with the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(df)
df2 = dt[, list(var=str_split(vars, ", ")[[1]]), by=id]
df2 = df2[!is.na(var), ]
```

One advantage of this is that if you have multiple ID columns (say, id, id2, id3), you can just change it to

```
df2 = dt[, list(var=strsplit(vars, ", ")[[1]]), by=c("id", "id2", "id3")]
```

Comment: Thanks, Ill have to check out the data.table package more!

Answer (score 2):

`concat.split.multiple` from my "splitstackshape" package has an option to perform the splitting and do the reshaping in one step, making the only thing left removing the rows with `NA` values:

```
library(splitstackshape)
out <- concat.split.multiple(df, "vars", ",", direction = "long")
out[complete.cases(out), ]
#    id var2 time  vars
# 1  X1    1    1   foo
# 2 X23    2    1 world
# 4  X1    1    2   bar
# 7  X1    1    3 hello
```

---

In [other scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16271419/1270695) the "guts" of the function [has fared quite well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16270786/1270695) with respect to speed. I've never benchmarked this particular functionality though (mostly because I never really deal with very large datasets to begin with).

Answer (score 1):

The `expand.grid` function is often useful for reshaping data.  For example:

```
> expand.grid(df[1,1],halfway[[1]])
  Var1  Var2
1   X1   foo
2   X1   bar
3   X1 hello
```

You can use `apply` to do this to each row of your data frame:

```
threequarterway <- lapply(seq(nrow(df)),function(i) expand.grid(df[i,1],halfway[[i]]))
```

and `do.call` to bind the resulting list elements into a single data frame:

```
df2 <- do.call(rbind,threequarterway)
```

Finally, get rid of the NA row as in David Robinson's answer:

```
df2 = df2[!is.na(df2[,2]),]
```

(David's answer appeared while I was typing this, and is probably a better method, but I thought you might like to know about `expand.grid` anyway.)