# Optimizing a "set in a string list" to a "set as a matrix" operation

Tags: r, optimization, string-matching

I have a set of strings which contain space-separated elements. I want to build a matrix which will tell me which elements were part of which strings. For example:

```
""
"A B C"
"D"
"B D"
```

Should give something like:

```
  A B C D
1
2 1 1 1
3       1
4   1   1
```

Now I've got a solution, but it runs slow as molasse, and I've run out of ideas on how to make it faster:

```
reverseIn <- function(vector, value) {
    return(value %in% vector)
}

buildCategoryMatrix <- function(valueVector) {
    allClasses <- c()
    for(classVec in unique(valueVector)) {
        allClasses <- unique(c(allClasses,
                               strsplit(classVec, " ", fixed=TRUE)[[1]]))
    }

    resMatrix <- matrix(ncol=0, nrow=length(valueVector))
    splitValues <- strsplit(valueVector, " ", fixed=TRUE)

    for(cat in allClasses) {
        if(cat=="") {
            catIsPart <- (valueVector == "")
        } else {
            catIsPart <- sapply(splitValues, reverseIn, cat)
        }
        resMatrix <- cbind(resMatrix, catIsPart)
    }
    colnames(resMatrix) <- allClasses

    return(resMatrix)
}
```

Profiling the function gives me this:

```
$by.self
                  self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"match"               31.20    34.74      31.24     34.79
"FUN"                 30.26    33.70      74.30     82.74
"lapply"              13.56    15.10      87.86     97.84
"%in%"                12.92    14.39      44.10     49.11
```

So my actual questions would be:
- Where are the 33% spent in "FUN" coming from? 
- Would there be any way to speed up the %in% call?

I tried turning the strings into factors prior to going into the loop so that I'd be matching numbers instead of strings, but that actually makes R crash. I've also tried going for partial matrix assignment (IE, resMatrix[i,x] <- 1) where i is the number of the string and x is the vector of factors. No dice there either, as it seems to keep on running infinitely.

Comment: See [this question and related answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267552/dummy-variables-from-a-string-variable) for an almost identical problem, just with numbers and a different value as a separator.

Comment: +1 for showing what effort you've taken and explaining what else you've tried though!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the similar question. I had done a quick search, but I really had no idea on which phrase/keyword to look for for this specific problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the development version of my "splitstackshape" package, there's a helper function called `charBinaryMat` that can be used for something like this:

[Here's the function](https://github.com/mrdwab/splitstackshape/blob/master/R/splitstackshape_helper_functions.R#L177) (since the version of the package on CRAN doesn't have it yet):

```
charBinaryMat <- function(listOfValues, fill = NA) {
  lev <- sort(unique(unlist(listOfValues, use.names = FALSE)))
  m <- matrix(fill, nrow = length(listOfValues), ncol = length(lev))
  colnames(m) <- lev
  for (i in 1:nrow(m)) {
    m[i, listOfValues[[i]]] <- 1
  }
  m
}
```

The input is expected to be the output of `strsplit`:

And here it is in use:

```
str <- c("" , "A B C" , "D" , "B D" )

## Fill is `NA` by default
charBinaryMat(strsplit(str, " ", fixed=TRUE))
#       A  B  C  D
# [1,] NA NA NA NA
# [2,]  1  1  1 NA
# [3,] NA NA NA  1
# [4,] NA  1 NA  1

## Can easily be set to another value
charBinaryMat(strsplit(str, " ", fixed=TRUE), fill = 0)
#      A B C D
# [1,] 0 0 0 0
# [2,] 1 1 1 0
# [3,] 0 0 0 1
# [4,] 0 1 0 1
```

---

#### Benchmarking

Since your question is about a faster approach, let's benchmark.

1. The functions for benchmarking:

   ```
   CBM <- function() {
     charBinaryMat(strsplit(str, " ", fixed=TRUE), fill = 0)
   }
   BCM <- function() {
     buildCategoryMatrix(str)*1L
   }
   Sapply <- function() {
     y <- unique( unlist( strsplit( str , " " ) ) )
     out <- t(sapply(str, function(x) y %in% unlist(strsplit(x , " " )),
                     USE.NAMES = FALSE )) * 1L
     colnames(out) <- y
     out
   }
   ```
2. Some sample data:

   ```
   set.seed(1)
   A = sample(10, 100000, replace = TRUE)
   str <- sapply(seq_along(A), function(x)
     paste(sample(LETTERS[1:10], A[x]), collapse = " "))
   head(str)
   # [1] "H G C"               "F H J G"             "H D J A I B"        
   # [4] "A C F H J B E G D I" "F C H"               "I C G B J D F A E"
   ```
3. Some sample output:

   ```
   ## Automatically sorted
   head(CBM())
   #      A B C D E F G H I J
   # [1,] 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
   # [2,] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
   # [3,] 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
   # [4,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   # [5,] 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
   # [6,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1

   ## Sorting just for comparison
   head(BCM())[, LETTERS[1:10]]
   #      A B C D E F G H I J
   # [1,] 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
   # [2,] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
   # [3,] 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
   # [4,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   # [5,] 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
   # [6,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1

   ## Sorting just for comparison
   head(Sapply())[, LETTERS[1:10]]
   #      A B C D E F G H I J
   # [1,] 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
   # [2,] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
   # [3,] 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
   # [4,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   # [5,] 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
   # [6,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
   ```
4. Benchmarking:

   ```
   library(microbenchmark)
   microbenchmark(CBM(), BCM(), Sapply(), times=20)
   # Unit: milliseconds
   #      expr        min         lq     median         uq        max neval
   #     CBM()   675.0929   718.3454   777.2423   805.3872   858.6609    20
   #     BCM() 11059.6305 11267.9888 11367.3283 11595.1758 11792.5950    20
   #  Sapply()  3536.7755  3687.0308  3759.7388  3813.4233  3968.3192    20
   ```

Comment: Creating a benchmark which one function call takes 11 seconds seems a bit excessive when you have sub-microsecond precision.

Comment: Thanks! This works and is lighting fast, though I really wish I understood why it works so much better than anything else I tried.

Comment: By the way: I found out that your function will fail if one of the original strings has leading/trailing spaces, leading to an empty string in  one of the vectors within the list. gsub("(^ +)|( +$)", "", originalVector) fixed that for me.

Comment: @EricFournier, I imagine that would be the case for all the answers, right? At any rate, in the "parent" function, [there is a "trim" command already](https://github.com/mrdwab/splitstackshape/blob/devel/R/concat.split.R#L86), but perhaps I will see whether it makes sense in the main function too. I think it would only matter when `sep = " "` but will have to test some more. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty easy to do with `vapply`:

```
x <- c("" , "A B C" , "D" , "B D" )
lines <- strsplit(x, " ", fixed = TRUE)

all <- sort(unique(unlist(lines)))

t(vapply(lines, function(x) all %in% x, numeric(length(all))))
```

This is a little slower than @Ananda's approach: https://gist.github.com/hadley/7169138

Comment: I'm debating whether to tell you that your benchmarks are inaccurate because you've hard-coded `x` into your function in your gist.

Comment: You have an O(1) algorithm in your timing gist! :-) But nice to see this alternative to `sapply` that is a lot cleaner to boot.

Comment: @hadley, I really wanted yours to be faster. `vapply` is one of those functions that I need to learn, so any examples like these are greatly appreciated.

Comment: @AnandaMahto basically you should never use `sapply` in a function, and instead use `vapply`. It's a little faster, but more importantly always returns an object of the same type/size.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way of doing this. There is a lot going on in the line where `out` is assigned. Basically, we loop over each element of your input vector. We split each element into individual characters, then we look to see which of these is present in a vector of all the unique values in your dataset. This returns either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. We use `* 1L` at the end to turn logical values into integer but you could just wrap the whole thing in `as.integer` instead.  `sapply` returns the results column-wise but you want them `row-wise` so we use the transpose function `t()` to achieve this.

The final line converts to a `data.frame` and applies column names.

```
#  Data
str <- c("" , "A B C" , "D" , "B D" )

#  Unique column headers (excluding empty strings as in example)
y <- unique( unlist( strsplit( str , " " ) ) )

#  Results
out <- t( sapply( str , function(x) y %in% unlist( strsplit( x , " " ) ) , USE.NAMES = FALSE ) ) * 1L

#  Combine to a data.frame
setNames( data.frame( out ) , y )
#  A B C D
#1 0 0 0 0
#2 1 1 1 0
#3 0 0 0 1
#4 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to break out with some Rcpp again, Simon.

Comment: @AnandaMahto lol. You can have this one. By the time i'm done no-one will care!!! :-)

Comment: @SimonO101, :) you seem dejected. +1, I do care. Go ahead and post us your solutions!