# Create several dummy variables from one string variable

Tags: r, string, dataframe, split, splitstackshape

I've tried pretty much everything from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16267552/1169233), but I can't get the results everyone else seems to be getting. This is my problem:

I have a data frame like this, listing the grades each teacher works with:

```
> profs <- data.frame(teaches = c("1st", "1st, 2nd",
                                  "2nd, 3rd",
                                  "1st, 2nd, 3rd"))
> profs
        teaches
1           1st
2      1st, 2nd
3      2nd, 3rd
4 1st, 2nd, 3rd
```

I've been looking for solutions to break the `teaches` variable into columns, like so:

```
  teaches1st teaches2nd teaches3rd
1          1          0          0
2          1          1          0
3          0          1          1
4          1          1          1
```

[I understand this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16271419/1169233) involving the `splitstackshape` library and the apparently deprecated `concat.split.expanded` function is supposed to do exactly what I want, given the answerer's explanation. However, I can't seem to reach the same results:

```
> concat.split.expanded(profs, "teaches", fill = 0, drop = TRUE)
Fehler in seq.default(min(vec), max(vec)) : 
  'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
```

Using `cSplit`, which I understood supersedes "most of the earlier concat.split* functions", I get this:

```
> cSplit(profs, "teaches")
   teaches_1 teaches_2 teaches_3
1:       1st        NA        NA
2:       1st       2nd        NA
3:       2nd       3rd        NA
4:       1st       2nd       3rd
```

I've tried using `cSplit`'s help and tweaking every one of those parameters, but I just can't get that split. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your concatenated data are concatenated character strings (not concatenated numerical values) you'll need to add `type = "character"` to get the function to work as you expect it.

The function's default setting is for numeric values, hence the error about `NaN` and so on.

The naming has been made more consistent with the short forms of the other functions in the same family. Thus, it is now `cSplit_e` (though the old function name would still work).

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit_e(profs, "teaches", ",", type = "character", fill = 0)
#         teaches teaches_1st teaches_2nd teaches_3rd
# 1           1st           1           0           0
# 2      1st, 2nd           1           1           0
# 3      2nd, 3rd           0           1           1
# 4 1st, 2nd, 3rd           1           1           1
```

The help page for `?concat.split.expanded` is the same as that of `cSplit_e`. If you have any tips on making it clearer to understand, please raise an issue at the package's GitHub page.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I got so focused on reading about `cSplit` I forgot to read the help for `concat.split.expanded` or `cSplit_e`. Those help files are pretty clear, I just wish there was a link to those functions at `?cSplit`.

Answer (score 2):

This is another option:

```
Vectorize(grepl, 'pattern')(c('1st', '2nd', '3rd'), profs$teaches)
#        1st   2nd   3rd
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# [4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try `mtabulate` from `qdapTools`

```
library(qdapTools)
res <- mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(profs$teaches), ', '))
colnames(res) <- paste0('teaches', colnames(res))
res
#    teaches1st teaches2nd teaches3rd
#1          1          0          0
#2          1          1          0
#3          0          1          1
#4          1          1          1
```

Or using `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
(vapply(c('1st', '2nd', '3rd'), stri_detect_fixed, logical(4L), 
                          str=profs$teaches))+0L
#     1st 2nd 3rd
#[1,]   1   0   0
#[2,]   1   1   0
#[3,]   0   1   1
#[4,]   1   1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround. It seems that `concat.split.expanded` works  if you have a string variable containing nothing but separators and numbers, i.e.:

```
> profs <- data.frame(teaches = c("1", "1, 2", "2, 3", "1, 2, 3"))
> profs
  teaches
1       1
2    1, 2
3    2, 3
4 1, 2, 3
```

Now `concat.split.expanded` works as on [Dummy variables from a string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16267552/1169233):

```
> concat.split.expanded(profs, "teaches", fill = 0, drop = TRUE)
  teaches_1 teaches_2 teaches_3
1         1         0         0
2         1         1         0
3         0         1         1
4         1         1         1
```

However, I'm still looking for a solution which doesn't involve removing all letters from my `teaches` variable.