# Splitting string column into many using tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, stringr

I have a string column with commas. I want to convert this single column into multiple labeled columns, with values filled in appropriately. The output data frame would have 3 columns (A, B, and C). Row 1 would have columns A and B filled in with "Yes", and C with "No". Row 2 would have all 3 columns filled with "Yes", etc.

```
df1 <- data.frame(X= c("A, B", "A, B, C", "A", "A, C"))

df1
        X
1    A, B
2 A, B, C
3       A
4    A, C
```

**Required Output**

```
A    B    C
Yes  Yes  No
Yes  Yes  Yes
Yes  No   No
Yes  No   Yes
```

Any hint, please.

Comment: [Dummy variables from a string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267552/dummy-variables-from-a-string-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(X) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(Y = "yes") %>% 
  spread(X, Y, fill = "no")

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   id [4]
     id A     B     C    
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 yes   yes   no   
2     2 yes   yes   yes  
3     3 yes   no    no   
4     4 yes   no    yes
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using `base R` with `table`.  We split the 'X' column by `,` into a `list` of `vector`s, convert it to a two column `data.frame` with `stack`, get the frequency with `table` and convert it to logical

```
table(stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(df1$X), ", +"), 
                    seq_len(nrow(df1))))[2:1]) > 0
 #   values
#ind    A     B     C
#  1 TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#  2 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#  3 TRUE FALSE FALSE
#  4 TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

Via `stringi`

```
stringi::stri_split_fixed(df1$X, ", ", simplify = TRUE) != ""
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
# [1,] TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [2,] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [3,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [4,] TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

`TRUE`/`FALSE` is essentially `yes`/`no` but if you need the character matrix you can always do `ifelse(., "yes", "no")` and retain the matrix structure.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different approach that doesn't rely on grouping. The final conversion to "Yes/"No" is also performed column-wise, rather than relying on a conversion from long to wide data. For a very large data set this may be somewhat more efficient.

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(row_num = 1:n()) %>% 
  separate_rows(X) %>% 
  spread(X, 1) %>% 
  select(-row_num) %>% 
  mutate_all(~ifelse(!is.na(.), 'Yes', 'No'))

    A   B   C
1 Yes Yes  No
2 Yes Yes Yes
3 Yes  No  No
4 Yes  No Yes
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
newdf=cSplit_e(df1, "X", sep = ", ",type = "character")
newdf[newdf==1]='Yes'
newdf[is.na(newdf)]='No'

newdf
        X X_A X_B X_C
1    A, B Yes Yes  No
2 A, B, C Yes Yes Yes
3       A Yes  No  No
4    A, C Yes  No Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution in `base`

```
lets <- strsplit(as.character(.subset2(df1,1L)), ', ')
lets_unique <- unique(unlist(lets))
vapply(seq_along(lets_unique),function(k)grepl(lets_unique[k],lets),logical(length(lets)))
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
# [1,] TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [2,] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [3,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [4,] TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```