# Split one column into several columns on basis of a separator in R

Tags: string, r, split, multiple-columns

I have a question similar to the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760730/splitting-one-column-into-multiple-columns)

If I have a data structure like the following:

```
 ROW_NO.        INPUT          STRAND
       1  1,888639,T,C             -1
       2  1,889158,G,C             NA                               
       3  1,889159,A,C             NA                                     
       4 1,978978,GC,G              1                                      
       5  1,982941,T,C             NA                                      
       6 1,1888193,C,A             -1
```

What do I need to do in order to split the INPUT column like so:

```
 ROW_NO.        INPUT    Chrom     Position    Ref.y   Variant.y   
       1  1,888639,T,C    chr1       888639        T           C
       2  1,889158,G,C    chr1       889158        G           C                            
       3  1,889159,A,C    chr1       889159        A           C                                         
       4 1,978978,GC,G    chr1       978978       GC           G        
       5  1,982941,T,C    chr1       982941        T           C        
       6 1,1888193,C,A    chr1      1888193        C           A
```

And I'd keep the STRAND column where it was, though somehow while formatting everything got messed up here so I left it out.

Answer (score 2):

Calling your dataset `df`:

```
library(stringr)
result <- data.frame(df,do.call(rbind,str_split(df$INPUT,",")))
result
#   ROW_NO.         INPUT STRAND X1      X2 X3 X4
# 1       1  1,888639,T,C     -1  1  888639  T  C
# 2       2  1,889158,G,C     NA  1  889158  G  C
# 3       3  1,889159,A,C     NA  1  889159  A  C
# 4       4 1,978978,GC,G      1  1  978978 GC  G
# 5       5  1,982941,T,C     NA  1  982941  T  C
# 6       6 1,1888193,C,A     -1  1 1888193  C  A
```

The rest is cosmetics:

```
colnames(result)[4:7] <- c("Chrom","Position","Ref.y","Variant.y")
result$Chrom <- paste0("chr",result$Chrom)
```

**EDIT** A note on the comments.

The suggested alternative:

```
result <- data.frame(df,do.call(rbind,strsplit(df$INPUT,",")))
```

fails if `df$INPUT` is a factor, which it might or might not be, depending on how you read in the data. The solution above, using `str_split(...)`, does not suffer from this deficiency.

Comment: I'm not sure what `stringr` is adding here, since `result <- data.frame(d,do.call(rbind,strsplit(d$INPUT,",")))` using just base will give the same result.

Comment: @Thomas, it's adding some waiting time :-)

Comment: Regarding your edit, even if `df$INPUT` is a factor, using `strsplit(as.character(df$INPUT), ...)` would still be faster. Unfortunately, some of the functions in "stringr" provide convenience at a very big time cost, and `str_split` is one of them.

Comment: My recommendation would be: `data.frame(mydf, do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(mydf$INPUT), ",", fixed = TRUE)))`. The `fixed = TRUE` will also give a good speed boost.

Answer (score 2):

If `d` is your dataframe, you can do this in base by applying the `read.csv` function to the `INPUT` column:

```
> out <- cbind(d, read.csv(text=d$INPUT, header=FALSE,
                           col.names=c('Chrom','Position','Ref.y','Variant.y')))
> out
  ROW_NO.         INPUT STRAND Chrom Position Ref.y Variant.y
1       1  1,888639,T,C     -1     1   888639     T         C
2       2  1,889158,G,C     NA     1   889158     G         C
3       3  1,889159,A,C     NA     1   889159     A         C
4       4 1,978978,GC,G      1     1   978978    GC         G
5       5  1,982941,T,C     NA     1   982941     T         C
6       6 1,1888193,C,A     -1     1  1888193     C         A
```

And, as in @jlhoward's answer, you can just use `paste` to get `Chrom` looking the way you want:

```
out$Chrom <- paste0('chr',out$Chrom)
```

Comment: I am getting this error: "Error in textConnection(text) : invalid 'text' argument"

Comment: @soosus, that error is pretty self-explanatory. Just wrap `d$INPUT` in `as.character` and your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend `concat.split` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
concat.split(mydf, "INPUT", ",")
#   ROW_NO.         INPUT STRAND INPUT_1 INPUT_2 INPUT_3 INPUT_4
# 1       1  1,888639,T,C     -1       1  888639       T       C
# 2       2  1,889158,G,C     NA       1  889158       G       C
# 3       3  1,889159,A,C     NA       1  889159       A       C
# 4       4 1,978978,GC,G      1       1  978978      GC       G
# 5       5  1,982941,T,C     NA       1  982941       T       C
# 6       6 1,1888193,C,A     -1       1 1888193       C       A
```

There is a faster version I've been working on that is currently [**only at this Gist**](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733). Eventually, it will replace the existing `concat.split` function.

```
cSplit(mydf, "INPUT", ",")
#    ROW_NO. STRAND INPUT_1 INPUT_2 INPUT_3 INPUT_4
# 1:       1     -1       1  888639       T       C
# 2:       2     NA       1  889158       G       C
# 3:       3     NA       1  889159       A       C
# 4:       4      1       1  978978      GC       G
# 5:       5     NA       1  982941       T       C
# 6:       6     -1       1 1888193       C       A
```